# Combine two or more columns into a new column

Tags: r, data-manipulation

My program asks the user for a path to an Excel file, reads the file into a data frame and writes it to a new Excel file using openxlsx.

Before I write the file, I want to combine two columns into a new one, and delete the two original columns. NULL values and blank cells should be ignored

The file looks like this:

```
ID      DATE        MED_1    Direction_1     MED_2    Direction_2
12345   9/2/2015    x        a               q        t
5678    9/3/2015    y        b                        NULL
9123    9/4/2015    NULL     NULL            s        v
```

What I want:

```
ID      DATE       MED  Direction
12345   9/2/2015    x   a
12345   9/2/2015    q   t
5678    9/3/2015    y   b
9123    9/4/2015    s   v
```

**EDIT - SOLUTION**
I ended up using melt as @akrun suggested, but I added a second id.var to retain `ORDERING_DATE`.

```
# Transform wide format into long format using melt 
dm1 <- melt(data = df, id.vars = c("TCCID", "ORDERING_DATE"), measure.vars = c("MED_1", "MED_2", "MED_4"), variable.name = "MED #", value.name = "Med Name")
```

Comment: You should take a look at this question, it will probably help you!

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7439/how-to-change-data-between-wide-and-long-formats-in-r

Comment: Thanks @GiovanaStein, I ended up using `melt` from the data.table package. According to the `melt` documentation "It is not necessary to load reshape2 any more. But if you have to, then load reshape2 package before loading data.table."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1), measure = patterns("^MED", "^Direction"),
     value.name = c("MED", "Direction"), na.rm = TRUE)[, variable := NULL][]
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, I ended up doing it a bit differently, but I did use melt from data.table. See my solution in my original post, thanks again!